# Problemas al mostrar icon de MasterDetailPage en Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo un MasterDetailPage el cual necesito cambiar el icono de sándwich​ por una imagen personalizada .png

En android la mestra perfectamente, el problema es en ios, muestra la imagen con un tipo de brackground que es el mismo del barTextColor:

iOS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Android:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como hacer que se muestre en iOS tal cual se muestra en Android?

Comment: tenes la imagen guardada en el proyecto de ios?

Comment: Si, lo tengo en la carpeta de Resources con propiedad de compilación BundleResources